# Can you assign a masterpage after/before "Page_PreInit"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to set the masterpage dynamically, But currently I have a base page with `Page_PreInit` that initializes/performs varioustasks needed for memberpages.

Now I know you could override the base page by putting  `(new protected void Page_OnInit(..))` in the member page but I don't want to as said the base page has got its job to do.

```
"this.MasterPageFile ="
```

Is there any way to set the masterpage after or before the `Page_PreInit`?
 
Or utilize both Page PreInt and BasePage PreInt ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### EDIT: Rereading your question, I see your problem:

```
public class BasePage : WebPage {
  protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //do stuff here
  }
}

public class MyPage : BasePage {
  protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //overwrites base class functionality
    //Pretty sure you can:
    base.Page_PreInit(sender,e);
  }
}
```

---

### Original answer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx#sectionToggle1

According to MSDN, you can assign it *during* `Page_PreInit`.

Is there a reason to do it before or after `Page_PreInit`? I'm not entirely sure anything useful comes before pre-init in the page life-cycle anyways.

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC386473.png))</sub>

There isn't an earlier hook, except the page constructor, if you could do it there. But you wouldn't have access to any of the page values yet.

Comment: I have used preInt in a base page for all my pages, I only need to assign the masterpage early to this one page.. so is it possible to do it after preInt ?

Comment: will try your latest edit now, will let you know if it works :)

Comment: And to be perfectly honest, I'm actually using this same method in my code, and it works fine for me (albeit I'm doing it with OnLoad and not Page_PreInit)